# Como permitir somente números e hífens com preg_replace?

Tags: php, regex

Estou com uma dúvida referente ao `preg_replace`, gostaria de saber como poderia fazer para permitir apenas números, e hifens (`-`).

O meu código é o seguinte:

```
$ola = preg_replace('/[^[:alnum:]_]/', '',$_POST['ola']);
```

Como poderei fazer para permitir apenas números e hifens?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

o preg_replace não é para checar e sim para remover, se quer remover tudo menos numeros e hifens faça assim:

```
$ola = preg_replace('/[^\d\-]/', '',$_POST['ola']);
```

> - `^` é negação
> - `\d` é qualquer numero
> - `\-` é hífen

Ou seja qualquer coisa que não é numero ou hífen.

Se quer validar, então talvez queira usar `preg_match`:

```
if (preg_match('/^[\d\-]+$/', $_POST['ola']) > 0) {
    echo 'Só é permitido números e hifens';
} else {
    echo 'Validou!';
}
```

Comment: @gmsantos mania de ctrl+c :/ ... obrigado

Answer (score 2):

Pode usar uma lista negando dígitos (`\d`) e o hifen (`-`) qualquer coisa que for casada é substituida por nada.

```
$str = "abaaksjjkdhaf 29023487 - 1kfksdjf";
echo preg_replace('/[^\d-]/i', '', $str);
```

Saída:

```
29023487-1
```

[Exemplo - ideone](http://ideone.com/HNlubE)

Answer (score 1):

Bem, sua dúvida não está muito clara e me parece ser um erro de conceito.

O [`preg_replace`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.preg-replace.php) é usado para **substituir** caracteres que casem com determinada *regex* com algum outro valor. Ou seja, não faz sentido usá-lo para **validar** ou algo do tipo.

Estou entendendo que **permitir** esteja mais ligado a **validar**, no sentido de caso a string apresente **qualquer** caractere que **não seja** um número ou um hífen, quero que ele seja **descartado**.

Nessa caso, a função mais adequada é o [`preg_match`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.preg-match.php). Com ela dá pra saber se a *string* atende essa regra ou não.

```
if (preg_match('/^[0-9\-]+$/', $_POST['ola'])) { 
    // É um valor válido, que só contém números e hifens... segue a vida
} else {
    // deu ruim
}
```

E o que essa *regex* faz?

`^` - Pega o ínicio da string

`[0-9-]` - Verifica se é um número de 0 até 9 ou um hífen (`[0-9]` pode ser substituído por `[\d]` também

`+` - Garante que a ocorrência da esquerda (números ou hifens) se repita pelo menos uma vez

`$` - Pega o final da string

Veja essa *regex* funcionando com [alguns exemplos](http://regexr.com/3fb0m).